# iOS 9 Transport Security Policy not blocking all http connections (only https was supposed to be allowed)

Tags: ios, http, https, ios9, app-transport-security

I have already researched and tested a lot this new feature of iOS 9, where the "Transport Security Policy" states that all HTTP requests would be blocked and only HTTPS would be allowed.

During my tests, I could download and render an image from an http ONLY link. After that, I put a http link to redirect the image's click and the TSP blocked my request.

Anyone has had this issue before?? What does the TSP actually block??

OBS.: I was NOT using a webview of any kind, before anyone asks...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In your Info.plist you can add a section that lists exceptions for the TSP. You can put http domains in that section. Hopefully that helps.

Comment: Maybe provide a little code or snippet of the plist file that you're referring to to improve your answer?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't run into the exact issue you're describing.

TSP, officially referred to as *App Transport Security (ATS)*, when enabled, forces you to use HTTPS.

Apple has a great [documentation page](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009251-SW33), which gets into *a lot* of details about what would and wouldn't get blocked.

If you're asking in order to get around it, you can include an `NSAppTransportSecurity` dictionary in your `Info.plist`. In it you can have specific domains for which you'd like an exception (`NSExceptionDomains`) or turn the whole thing off (`NSAllowsArbitraryLoads : YES`). Note that the spirit of the latter is for an app that allows the user to specify the connection info, not exactly to work around security best practices.

Comment: I am trying to understand when I have to use HTTPS, because I have a lot of outside HTTP links and I would have to change them. But I was testing a sample and some HTTP worked and other didn't. I haven't touched those exceptions you mentioned, so that my results would be unbiased. Seems like it didn't really work out for me rs.

Comment: @bcg07 Are you free to share which links worked and which didn't? I can't think of any other way to help without a concrete example of some HTTP links working even though ATS is supposed to be turned on.